# Tag plus is Protected

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I tried to make function, but it Mathematica showed this massage:

```
Tag Plus in (20 x^3+x^2/(2+x^2)^(3/2)-1/Sqrt[2+x^2])[x_] is Protected.
```

This function I wrote:

```
labFunctionDD[x_] = D[D[x^5 + 2 - 6 x - Sqrt[x^2 + 2], x], x];
```

Does somebody know how to solve this problem?

Comment: After restart it somehow ran

Comment: Nevertheless you should almost certainly replace `=` with `:=` and refer to the Mathematica documentation to learn the difference between them.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, There no need to use := because D function returns new function. So I don't need to define new

Answer (score 2):

just to explain the error, we can see (from the error message) that you must have previously defined

```
 labFunctionDD = D[D[x^5 + 2 - 6 x - Sqrt[x^2 + 2], x], x];
```

then tried to define

```
 labFunctionDD[x_] ...
```

which fails because the symbol `labFunctionDD` is already defined and mathematica uses the first def in the second expression.

Good habit to restart the kernel whenever you see such strange errors, although if you understood the cause you could have done `Clear[labFunctionDD]`